# After moving EntityFramework Core migrations to another project, they stopped working

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP .NET Core 2.1 application which uses the Entity Framework Core as the ORM. The DB is PostgreSQL. Migrations were located in one project, then I moved them to another one, and they stopped working. I changed the namespaces for all Models and Context classes. Still no success. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: the docs may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"? Do you receive any error or unexpected result? Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Are you saying the migrations are not in the same assembly containing your db context? If yes, you'd probably need to utilize [MigrationsAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaldbcontextoptionsbuilder-2.migrationsassembly?view=efcore-2.1) method, e.g. `UseNpgsql(connection_string, o => o.MigrationsAssembly(...))`